Adding user and item features to LightFM Model
I am training a LightFM model for a recommender system, I create my interactions dataset successfully then try to add user and item features but face a consistent error stating the following (ValueError: Feature False not in feature mapping. Call fit first.). I have read the documentation and made sure the items and users datasets are as required, and I use fit before creating them. Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
from lightfm import LightFM
from lightfm.data import Dataset

df_item_features = df_item_features[['product_id', 'category_l1', 'category_l2', 'category_l3']]
df_user_features = df_user_features[['user_id', 'segment', 'region']]

# Apply one-hot encoding to user and item features
df_user_features = pd.get_dummies(df_user_features, columns=['segment', 'region'])
df_item_features = pd.get_dummies(df_item_features, columns=['category_l1', 'category_l2', 'category_l3'])

# Extract user and item feature columns excluding the IDs
user_feature_columns = df_user_features.columns.drop('user_id')
item_feature_columns = df_item_features.columns.drop('product_id')

# Build the LightFM Dataset
dataset = Dataset()
dataset.fit(
    users=df_interactions['user_id'].unique(),
    items=df_interactions['product_id'].unique(),
    user_features=user_feature_columns,
    item_features=item_feature_columns
)

# Build interaction matrix
(interactions, weights) = dataset.build_interactions(
    [(row['user_id'], row['product_id'], row['interaction_strength']) for _, row in df_interactions.iterrows()]
)

num_users, num_items = dataset.interactions_shape()
print(f'Num users: {num_users}, num_items {num_items}.')

# Build user and item features matrices
user_features = dataset.build_user_features(
    [(row['user_id'], [str(f) for f in row[1:]]) for _, row in df_user_features.iterrows()]
)

item_features = dataset.build_item_features(
    [(row['product_id'], [str(f) for f in row[1:]]) for _, row in df_item_features.iterrows()]
)

print(repr(user_features))
print(repr(item_features))


Any clue why this error comes up? appreciate your help.
